# How do I provide runtime specific configuration metadata to Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, factory

I'm writing a client/server app and configuring it with Spring.

My client interface handles marshalling requests to the server and handling the responses.

At the moment, I have a factory that looks something like:

```
public class ClientFactory {
    private ApplicationContext ctx;
  public ClientFactory(){
    ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class);
  }

  public MyClient(String host, int port){
    MyClient client = ...
    // create a connection to the server
    return client;
  }
}
```

Now, MyClient has a bunch of dependencies that I would like to inject, so I would like to create the MyClient instance using Spring and use @Inject annotations to inject the dependencies.

How do I pass the host/port as configuration metadata into the Spring configuration?  If I can't what is the recommended alternative.  I could do all the wiring myself, but then that is what Spring is for.

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

You should check configuration part of the spring reference. For example you can create beans like this with spring 3.x.

```
@Configuration
// spring config that loads the properties file
@ImportResource("classpath:/properties-config.xml")
public class AppConfig {

    /**
     * Using property 'EL' syntax to load values from the
     * jetProperties value
     */
    private @Value("#{jetProperties['jetBean.name']}") String name;
    private @Value("#{jetProperties['jetBean.price']}") Long price;
    private @Value("#{jetProperties['jetBean.url']}") URL url;

    /**
     * Create a jetBean within the Spring Application Context
     * @return a bean
     */
    public @Bean(name = "jetBean")
    JetBean jetBean() {
        JetBean bean = new JetBeanImpl();
        bean.setName(name);
        bean.setPrice(price);
        bean.setUrl(url);
        return bean;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but this still requires a pre-defined properties file that contains the required jetProperties definitions.  I would like these to be specified at runtime.  Perhaps I can look into creating these properties on the fly.

Comment: Beans are created at runtime. It means that these setName, setPrice methods can be set with custom runtime logic. You dont have to use pre-defined properties.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using a static configuration class.

```
public class ClientFactory {
    private ApplicationContext ctx;
  public ClientFactory(){
    ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class,ServerConfig.class);
  }

  public MyClient(String host, int port){
    MyClient client = ...
    // create a connection to the server
    return client;
  }

  @Data
  @AllArgsConstructor
  public static class ServerDetails{
     private int port;
     private String host;
  }

  @Configuration
  public static class ServerConfig{
     static String host;
     static int port;

     @Bean
     public void serverDetails(){
        return new ServerDetails(host, port);
     }
  }
}
```

It feels very clunky though.  Is there a better way?